# How can I fetch an API in Flutter and handle the 'ChromeProxyService' internal error?

Tags: flutter, api

I am trying to Fetch API but i'm getting this Error !

"ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression 'information': InternalError: Expression evaluation in async frames is not supported. No frame with index 30"

The api i am calling is written in XML format and i wathc so many videos API calling etc. but no one works for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

String store;
Map mapresponse;

class Hhh extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hhh({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hhh> createState() => _HhhState();
}

class _HhhState extends State<Hhh> {
  List<dynamic> users = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Title(
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          child: const Center(
              child: Text(
            'Go Kullu',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white70,
                fontFamily: AutofillHints.addressCity,
                fontSize: 40),
          )),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
        height: 100.sp,
        width: 150.sp,
        child: Card(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          elevation: 50,
          //shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(66, 241, 156, 227),
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 177, 255),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => fetchusers(),
                child: const Text('SelectDistrict'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  void fetchusers() async {
    print("User called");
    const url = 'http://10.146.50.43/gokullu/api/district';
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final body = response.body;
    final josn = jsonDecode(body);
    setState(() {
      users = josn["DistrictName"]["DistrictCode"];
    });
    print('fetching completed');
  }
}
```

Comment: Which specific line in your code is generating the error, or which is the last line to execute before the error? Does the http.get return data?

Comment: it shows error in widget inspector that is " nosuchmethoderror:class String has no instance method with matching arguments.